# Change lowercase letters to: numbers 00-25, and uppercase letters to: numbers 26-51

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, numbers

I have already tried a couple different methods and come away with no avail. We need to perform this with simple operators and simple loops. Here is what I have tried:

```
def str2num(inputstr):
    i = ''

    for x in inputstr:

        i = i + str.replace(x, str(ord(x)),1)
    i = str(i)

    print(i)
```

Came away with an error stating that in integer cannot be converted to a string implicitly, which I tried to fix with the str(ord(x), but I still received the same error.

Then I decided I would try to convert to a list and use the import string...things got messy:

```
def str2num(s):

    import string

    r = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase
    L = list(r)

    for i in L:
        L [i] = 00 + 1

    print(L)
```

I am out of solutions that I can come up with, any suggestions? Remember (and I know it is a pain, but) simple solutions only. Use for, with, while, if, import string, and general mathematical operators. This class is not about efficiency, but using the basic tools to get the job done.

Thank you.

Comment: I also must be able to enter a value in the def str2num() parentheses and have it give me a code using the aforementioned numbers.

Comment: You're trying to replace something in a string with the integer `1`; that's the error. You may want `"1"` instead, although it's not really clear to me what you're doing in that code anyway.

Comment: Here is the question:

Comment: Suppose we use two-digit numbers to encode the English lower-case and uppercase alphabet. So, letter a is encoded as 00, letter b as 01, letter c as 02, …., letter z as 25, letter A as 26, letter B as 27, …., and letter Z as 51. Write a python function, call it str2num(s), that returns the above encoding of string s. For example, str2num('MyHome') should return string '382433141204'

Comment: Therefore I am being asked to convert string characters into numbers, and have it printed back to me in a string of those numbers.

Comment: Ok, but why are you trying to replace every single letter with a 1?

Comment: I guess that is where I am unsure of the notation involved. I want 'a' to be '00', 'b' to be '01' and so forth. So I began with for i in L:

Comment: oops, didn't mean to press enter (still in my idle world lol) and then replace each value with the values: '00', '01', '01'... but I do not know how to tell Python to do that in a loop. Do I add 1 each time? If so, what is the proper way to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of numbers:

```
In [172]: t='abcABC'

In [175]: l = map(lambda x: ord(x)-97 if x.islower() else ord(x)-65+26, t)

In [176]: l
Out[176]: [0, 1, 2, 26, 27, 28]
```

To get a string with `1` to `'01'`:

```
In [179]: ''.join('%02d'%i for i in l)
Out[179]: '000102262728'
```

function version:

```
In [186]: def str2num(s):
     ...:   res=[]
     ...:   for i in s:
     ...:       if i.islower():
     ...:           res.append(ord(i)-97)
     ...:       else:
     ...:           res.append(ord(i)-65+26)
     ...:   return ''.join('%02d'%i for i in res)

In [187]: str2num('MyHome')
Out[187]: '382433141204'
```

Comment: If you're going to do someone's homework for them, doing it in a way that uses `map` and `lambda` so they'll fail for cheating seems kind of cruel.

Comment: lambda is something we have not learned so will not be acceptable for an answer unfortunately (per the professor's request)

Comment: That tag hasn't been used on the site for like 2 years. It's *clearly* homework from the problem statement.

Comment: Not homework, but examples of the types of problems seen on exams and quizzes.

Comment: Couldn't you simplify lambda?
l = map(lambda x: ord(x)-97 if x.islower() else ord(x)-39, t)

Comment: @MichaelBurns just want to make it clear. The compiler will simplify that ;)

Comment: @ringlei2 you can convert the lambda exp to function yourself, or see updates ;)

Comment: @zhangxaochen Thank you, I think I can work with this for now and fiddle around some more. I am at least on a better track than before, and ...

Comment: @Wooble you need not be cruel, I was simply asking for guidance, not for someone to do my homework

Comment: @zhangxaochen - Accepted, but alas, I am a newbie and cannot upvote, but thank you.

Comment: @ringlei2 glad to help ;) BTW, you can edit your question to let others see the details, don't write them in comment

Answer (score 0):

use somestring.islower() and somestring.isUpper()

for lowercase its str(ord(somestring[i])-97) to get 0 - 25 for a-z

for uppercase str(ord(somestring[i])-65+26) to get 26 - 51 for A-Z

i don't know how you want to code it but this should help alot. use ur Ascii table ;)

also this doesn't check for 2 digits so you're gonna need to figure that out too if you want things like 00, 01, etc...